# Stuck with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I have big string in that I need to check if number is present which is more than 3.
Means "some string2" will be invalid , but "some string 3","some string7" will be correct.

Comment: Currently I am using [3-6] , but I don't want to add upper limit.

Comment: Thanks used /Android [3-9].*/ , I am using this to detect versions of android , if  they'll change naming convention then I am screwed.

Comment: This won't work when they release version 10. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/some\s*string\s*([3-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]+)/i', $haystack);
```

And here the working [example](http://regexr.com?31j96)

But, after examining your use-case, which seems to be checking for a specific version in an application description, I too would advise you to just get the number out of the string and compare it to an actual number to be sure it's larger or equal than 3:

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+)/', $string, $matches);
if ($matches[1] >= 3) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex is for text matching, not arithmetic.  Right tool for the right job...

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+)/', $string, $matches);
if ($matches[1] >= 3) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Definitely a better solution than using regex.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't work?

```
$numberBiggerThanThree = preg_match('/([0-9]{2,}|[3-9])/', 'some long string 3');
```

Comment: What about two digit numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You match a word followed by an optional space and then the number greater than 2. Thanks to the decimal places you can control that:

```
(\w*\s*(?:[1-9]\d+|[3-9]))
```

Some  little example ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xvJRLu)):

```
$subject = 'I have big string in that I need to check if number is present which is more than 3.
Means "some string2" will be invalid , but "some string 3","some string7" will be correct.';

$pattern = '(\w*\s*(?:[1-9]\d+|[3-9]))';

$r = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "than 3"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "string 3"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "string7"
  }
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I modified Florian's solution:

```
[a-z]+\s?[a-z]+\s?([1-9][0-9]+|[3-9])
```

http://regexr.com?31ja1

It works for any string and not just "some string" and it allows only 0 or 1 whitespace character.

Comment: Good addition. Still, after examining his use-case, I too would advise against the use of a regular expression.